# Create multiple records from one request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, activerecord

I started with a simple controller which would allow a user to create a single instance by selecting a user from a collection select.  Initially this was fine but the users ended up needing to perform this action twenty or more times.

To ease the burden on the users I want to change this from selecting from a drop-down to selecting multiple items using check boxes.  This turned my simple controller into a complicated function that required a transaction to ensure all or none of the records were created and ended up breaking things in the view such as reporting errors.

What is the best design pattern for this using Rails?  Basically I'm looking a good way to do a batch create that still works with the traditional Rails MVC.  This must be something that has been encountered numerous times before but I can't seem to find a solution that doesn't require some hacks.

Comment: A snippet of your models and what you actually want to do with them will really help.

Answer (score 0):

To clean up your controller, you can use Service Object pattern.
https://netguru.co/blog/service-objects-in-rails-will-help

Probably you can split your logic into multiple classes.